# Python not taking in user input correctly

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, input

So I'm creating a small hangman game to practice my Python and before I code the `"Y"` or `"Yes"` conditional portion of my code I decided to test out the responses to make sure it takes in the user inputs correctly. Unfortunately when I enter `"N"` or `"No"` the code doesn't skip past the `"Y"` or `"Yes"` portion of my code and returns

> "Welcome to a game of Hangman!
> Please type in Y or Yes to play or N or No to quit no
> Yay! I'm glad you decided to play! Hmm let me guess a word.................ok DONE!
> Please type in a letter or guess the word!"

....any ideas why it's not skipping the `"Yes"` portion of the code?

```
import random

list_of_words = ["banana", "monster", "development", "anarchy", "congruence", "display", "algorithm"]

word_chosen = random.choice(list_of_words)

print("Welcome to a game of Hangman! ")
user_response = str(input("Please type in Y or Yes to play or N or No to quit ")).lower()

if user_response == 'y' or 'yes':
    print("Yay! I'm glad you decided to play! Hmm let me guess a word.................ok DONE!")
    letter_guess = str(input("Please type in a letter or guess the word! ")).lower()
    
elif user_response == 'n' or 'no':
    print("Awww well come back next time if you'd like to play HANGMAN!!!! DUN DUN DUNNNN ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your if conditions need some modifications:

use

```
if user_response == 'y' or user_response == 'yes':
```

instead of

```
if user_response == 'y' or 'yes':
```

and use

```
elif user_response == 'n' or user_response == 'no':
```

instead of

```
elif user_response == 'n' or 'no':
```

the problem is because the boolean value of a non-empty string is equal to `True`.

```
print(bool('yes'))
# True
```

Comment: Yes! This worked! Thank you for the response!

Comment: @jvjvalerio you're welcome. I glad that I helped :)